# Can I reduce the spacing between li numbers & content?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to lessen the spacing between the ordinals and the content, i.e I want to change from:

```
1.  foo
```

to:

```
1. foo
```

Is this possible?

```html
<ol>
    <li>...content</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `list-style-position:inside;`

Comment: This would work. You need to negate the extra white-space added to the left of the bullet though, making sure that it is consistent between browsers.

Comment: This will have possible unintended side-effects for wrapping text. additionally, this doesn't allow you to change the space between the number and the content in chrome.

Comment: I don't see how this works. This just indents the entire list item even further. It also doesn't illustrate how/where to use it.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with a span

```
<ol>
  <li><span style="margin-left: -10px">near</span></li>
  <li>normal</li>
</ol>
```

You can also do something like this:

```
<ol>
  <li style="text-indent: -5px">near</li>
  <li>normal</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: No, I want to _reduce_ the padding

Comment: @user578895 This does effectively reduce it. Notice the negative value on the property values.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you can *increase* the space using `padding-left`, but not decrease it.

I believe you will need to settle on an alternative work-around, such as wrapping each list item's contents with a div or span tag and giving that tag a negative margin-left.